# Variation of constants on a second order DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given is the DE $$\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}+z=\frac{\mu}{x^2}z$$
I have to prove that for $0<a\leqslant x$, $$z(x)=z(a)\cos(x-a)+z'(a)\sin(x-a) + \int_a^x \sin(x-\xi)\frac{\mu}{\xi^2}z(\xi) \, d\xi$$
I think it is a good idea to use variation of constants. So first I solved $\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}+z=0$, giving me $z(x)=c_1\sin(x)+c_2\cos(x)$, with $c_1, c_2$ constants. Then, I wrote $z(x)=u_1(x)\sin(x)+u_2(x)\cos(x)$ and calculated $z'(x)$ and $z''(x)$ accordingly. But here I got lost.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: By using variation of constants you transformed a differential equation into an integral equation (observe that the unknown function appears under the integral sign).  And the original DE has solution expressed in terms of [Bessel functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunction.html).  Mathematica gives $$c_1 \sqrt{x} \, J_{\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{4 \mu +1}}(x)+c_2 \sqrt{x} \,Y_{\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{4 \mu +1}}(x)$$

Comment: Okay, but I still don't see how this would give me my $z(x)$...

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you:  thought you were interested in _solving the equation_ rather than _transforming it into an integral equation_.  Just take a formula for the variation of parameters for the nonhomogeneous equation $z''(x) + z(x) = f(x)$ (see, e.g. [Variation of parameters exercise — harmonic motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1801418/variation-of-parameters-exercise-harmonic-motion)) and substitute $\frac{\mu}{x^2} z(x)$ for $f(x)$.  After some trig you should get the integral equation.

Answer (score 2):

$$z(x)=z(a)\cos(x-a)+z'(a)\sin(x-a) + \int_a^x \sin(x-\xi)\frac{\mu}{\xi^2}z(\xi) \, d\xi$$
$$z''(x)=-z(a)\cos(x-a)-z'(a)\sin(x-a) +  \frac {\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \int_a^x \sin(x-\xi)\frac{\mu}{\xi^2}z(\xi) \, d\xi$$
Use Leibniz rule for the derivative of the integral... Then check if z is a solution of the equation..
$$\frac {\partial}{\partial x} \int_a^x \sin(x-\xi)\frac{\mu}{\xi^2}z(\xi) \, d\xi= \int_a^x \frac {\partial}{\partial x}\sin(x-\xi)\frac{\mu}{\xi^2}z(\xi) \, d\xi= \int_a^x  \cos(x-\xi)\frac{\mu}{\xi^2}z(\xi) \, d\xi$$
$$\frac {\partial}{\partial x} \int_a^x \cos(x-\xi)\frac{\mu}{\xi^2}z(\xi) \, d\xi= -\int_a^x \sin(x-\xi)\frac{\mu}{\xi^2}z(\xi) \, d\xi+\frac{z(x)\mu}{x^2}$$
Therefore
$$\frac {\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \int_a^x \sin(x-\xi)\frac{\mu}{\xi^2}z(\xi) \, d\xi=-\int_a^x \sin(x-\xi)\frac{\mu}{\xi^2}z(\xi) \, d\xi+\frac{z(x)\mu}{x^2}$$
The variation of constants is for differential equation with constants coefficients...Here you have a function of x.

Comment: Okay, I see that this works. But this doesn't really explain how to get my $z(x)$.

Comment: @DavidW. It shows that the formula for z is correct but as you said it dosent help you establish it...Use wronskian and the formula for particular solution to 2 order linear differential equation and consider whats on the right side of your equation as a function $f(x)$ and whats on the  left side as a 2order linear equation with constant coefficients

Answer (score 0):

Variation of constant does not work here, because the right hand side has a $z$ in it.  In fact this is a homogeneous differential equation.$$\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}+z=\frac{\mu}{x^2}z \iff   \frac{d^2z}{dx^2}+(1-\frac{\mu}{x^2})z=0            $$